# How can I draw 3-dimensional plot with square root in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to draw a plot with function `z=sqrt(9-x.^2-y.^2) (x=[-3,3],y=[-3,3])`

But matlab doesn't draw a plot.

How can I draw plot with given function?

Comment: show us what you have done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matlab needs a `meshgrid` to plot 3d data as a surface. However your function allows for negative roots, resulting in complex results for `z`. This cannot be accurately represented by any 3d plot. To better see the surface, I would recommend to use `surf(X,Y,z(X,Y))` but `surf` can't handle complex input.

```
x = -3:0.1:3;
y = x;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
z = @(x,y) sqrt(9-x.^2-y.^2);
plot3(X,Y,z(X,Y));
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick way is to use [`fsurf`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fsurf.html) (or [`ezsurf`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ezsurf.html) in Matlab versions before R2016a) with an [anonymous function](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html). However, this option allows less control than manually creating the grid and calling `surf` as in [Dennis Klopfer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46628283/2586922).

```
fsurf(@(x,y) sqrt(9-x.^2-y.^2), [-3 3 -3 3])
```

[image]